# Populate nested form fields into dropdown list

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravityforms

I have managed to get the fields from my nested form field into the dropdown list.

However, I would like to include a placeholder of "Please select a name" instead of straightaway populate all the fields.

Any idea where should I add that?

```
property_unique_entries=property_uniquee_ntries+'<option value="'+$(this).html()+'">'+$(this).html()+'</option>';


 $(".specialname button.gpnf-add-entry,.specialname li.edit a").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
    $("select#input_10_1").html(property_unique_entries);               
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Although old, this post provide code for dynamically populating a dropdown field and manually add a placeholder https://legacy.forums.gravityhelp.com/topic/dynamic-ajax-category-child-dropdown ; Also, could you share in your question your code to populate a dropdown from nested form ? cheers

Comment: and a more recent and academic exemple https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_render/